# Running Java program/Jar from command line

Tags: java, maven, command-line, jar, executable-jar

I have a java program that I coded in intellij using maven. I exported it as a jar and tried running from the command line but it keeps on telling me

Error: Could not find or load main class com.company.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.Main

I then attempted to run the program itself from the command line and that also tells me it cannot find the main class

command line:
for the jar: java -jar selenium_project.jar

for running the program :java com.company.Main

For the jar I am running it from the folder it is in. For the program I am running it from the root of the program.

Pom.xml

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <index>true</index>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.company.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins></build>
```

Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.company.Main
```

It might be an issue with maven, I dont know. I created a simple hello world program and ran that from the command line and it worked. I ran it like this (c://etc)../src/> java com.company.HelloWorld. But again when i try for this one it cannot find the main class.
Thank you

[These are my classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eit0H.png)

EDIT:
I changed to use the maven-assembly-plugin and I rebuilt the jar and still does not work

```
<build>

<plugins>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>
                                com.company.Main
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

</plugins></build>
```

[class structure to show where main class is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvpAa.png)

code in the Main class

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
    System.out.println("hello");

    Executor ex = new Executor();

}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure there is a Main.class file inside the jar you exported? Try running `jar tvf selenium_project.jar` . One of the entries must be `com/company/Main.class` . Do you see it?

Comment: I got huge list of  that went so far that I cant even see the top of it. What does that command do?
here is the top line i can see 
 237 Mon Dec 21 15:31:02 EST 2020 org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/ec/SignatureSpi$1.class

Comment: You may be using the wrong jar. Selenium is a testing framework if I'm not mistaken. Are you sure you want to call that jar? You can filter the list like this: `jar tvf selenium_project.jar | grep Main.class`

Comment: I get this  - 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.....I created the jar, it is a testing framework but i built a simple web scraper with it and that is what i turned into a jar

Comment: Sorry, assumed you were on Linux. It's very likely that you do not have a class called com.company.Main in the jar. Does that class even exist in your source tree? In layman's terms, the goal of the `java` command is to execute the static main method on a given class. Here you've given the class to be com.company.Main. So java first needs to find that class file and then invoke the main method. Using that information try to figure out if the class file exists, and if it has a main method.

Comment: You didn't create the executable JAR correctly: https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven

Comment: it wouldnt explain though why running the java program itself does not work - when i run java com.company.Main it also does not work. And i do have a Main.class

Comment: Do i need to run it as a maven program like mvn for it to work?

Comment: No, `java -jar xxx.jar` is fine. Check with 7zip or such the jar (is a zip file). Then check the case-sensitive path com/main/Main.class and the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. And do not forget the libraries/dependencies. Class-Path in manifest to lib/*.jar or such. Maven copy dependencies.

Comment: @joopEggen What about to just run the program itself from the command line? Would I need to use mvn for that?

Comment: My program uses a line that sets a property that is external - could that be the issue? here is the line - 

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
...to clarify the program runs in intellij its the command line i am having issues with

Answer (score 0):

Your error is probably that your Main class is in the wrong package.

Furthermore, please not that you need the Maven shade plugin or Maven assembly plugin to build executable jars if you have dependencies.

Comment: Edited above - I tried it the maven assembly plugin with no luck

Comment: You also need to check for the Main class. I still doubt that it is in the right package. Is the package really called `com.company`? You can also unpack the JAR and check in which directory the Main class resides.

Comment: I added the class structure above and the code in my "Main" class

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what the issue was. I tried creating a new program and i copied over the classes and remade the pom.xml file and my new program works except for one dependency (chrome options) but I dont think that is what was causing an issue. So now I just need to figure out why Chrome options wont work but the actual jar from the new program does run.

Answer (score -1):

From： https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/54971948.html
To extract the files from a jar file, use x , as in: C:\Java> jar xf myFile.jar. To extract only certain files from a jar file, supply their  Install an archive program. JAR files work just like ZIP files. You can use any archive program to extract them. 2. Find the JAR file you want to extract. Use File Explorer (press Win + E to open File Explorer) or Finder on Mac to 3. Right-click the JAR file. Doing so . How to extract manifest file from jar. Extracting the Contents of a JAR File.